# Balanced Parenthesis, Stack not iterating to the other lines in text file

Tags: c, stack

I'm reading a text file to determine whether the parenthesis in said file is balanced (for every open parenthesis there is a closed one). The code is running, but it's not exactly reading the data accurately from the file, and it's not reading line by line. What is the error?
Here is the data that the text file contains
() 
[] 
[ 
] 
{} 
{

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 1000

struct Stack{
    int top;
    char arr[MAX_SIZE];
} st;

void init(){
    st.top = -1;
}

bool isEmpty(){
    if(st.top == -1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

bool isFull(){
    if(st.top == MAX_SIZE-1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

void push(char item){
    if(isFull()){
            printf("Stack is full");
    }else{
        st.top++;
        st.arr[st.top] = item;
    }
}

void pop(){
    if(isEmpty()){
        printf("Stack is empty");
    }else{
        st.top--;
    }
}

char gettop(){
    return st.arr[st.top];
}

bool ArePair(char opening,char closing)
{
    if(opening == '(' && closing == ')') return true;
    else if(opening == '{' && closing == '}') return true;
    else if(opening == '[' && closing == ']') return true;
    return false;
}

void main()
{
    int length=0; //,i,j;
    init();
    int i;
    char output[MAX_SIZE];

    FILE * filepointer;
    filepointer = fopen("ajay1.txt", "r");


        if(filepointer == NULL)
            {
                printf("No File Found");
                return 1;
            }

       for(i=0; fgets(output, sizeof(output), filepointer) !=NULL; i++)
          {



     //fclose(filepointer);
    // init();

    //printf("Enter an expression to check:");
    //gets(output);

    length = strlen(output);

    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
        if(output[i] == '(' || output[i] == '{' || output[i] == '['){
                push(output[i]);
        }else if(output[i] == ')' || output[i] == '}' || output[i] == ']'){
            char a = gettop();
            printf("%c",a);
            if(isEmpty() || !ArePair(gettop(),output[i])){
                printf("\nResult - Invalid expression - Not a Balanced one !");
                return 0;
            }else{
                pop();
            }
        }
    }
    if(isEmpty()){
        printf("\nResult - Valid expression - Perfectly Balanced !");
    }else{
        printf("\nResult - Invalid expression - Not a Balanced one !");
    }
}
 fclose(filepointer);

}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code for someone to wade through spotting an ambiguous bug for you. Most of it seems irrelevant to the problem. Make a copy and cut it down, just read the file, print each line, ensure that they are as expected. You will probably find the issue yourself, if not try posting another question with the much reduced code set.

Comment: I edited it. The error that i noticed is that even though there are two characters on the same line from the text file, it only saves the first one it encounters and doesnt save the other one, so the answer is that it's always unbalanced. I'm not sure how to fix this. Also its not giving the result of the entire file like i said, only the first value

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  amongst other things, `void main()` is not a valid signature for the function: `main`  there are only two valid signatures: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *arv[] )`  and it is missing the necessary `#include` statements.  Are you expecting us to guess as to which header files are included?

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please indent after every opening brace '{',  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: regarding: `for(i=0;i<output;i++){` and the following statements. what are you expecting this statement to do?  Note: it is comparing the index 'i' with the address of the array `output[]`

Comment: i posted the entire code @user3629249. It should compile now, my apologies

Comment: Note: never use the function: `gets()`  it has been depreciated for years and completely removed from the latest C standard

Comment: regarding: `struct Stack{
    int top;
    char arr[MAX_SIZE];
} st;`  for flexibility, it is best to separate the definition of a struct from an instance of the struct

Comment: regarding: `length = strlen(output);`  the variable `length` is declared as `int` while the function `strlen()` returns a `size_t`  While the implicit conversion feature of C will 'usually' save your code, it is best to write the code so there are no 'implicit' conversions

Comment: regarding statements like: `printf("Stack is empty");`  1) it is best to write so the code is easily readable.  I.E place an appropriate space inside parens, inside braces, inside brackets, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators  2) the function `printf()` is very CPU intensive.  Suggest using: `puts()` where appropriate

Comment: I used gets() since it was the only way I had known to integrate the stack modular code to the file code. My intention is to read the file and store the values in an array, then go through each value to either push or pop based on whether it opened with {, [, ( or closed with },],). The output is partially giving me the answer however it's not accurate as to display what's exactly written in the file

Comment: OT: the streams in C are buffered (this can be overridden by the code)  everything written to the terminal will put into the buffer.  To get the data displayed to the terminal one of several different things much be done: 1) the buffer overflows  2) a input operation is performed on the same stream 3) the function: `fflush()` is called for that stream 4) a newline '\n' is output to that stream.

Comment: this kind of function signature: `void init()` when there is no preceding prototype statement (which would have 'void' between the parens) results in the compiler producing code that is expecting any number/type of parameters.  Usually not what you want

Comment: regarding: `printf("No File Found");`  when outputting error messages, as this statement is doing, the message should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and if the error was from a C library function, then the text reason the system thinks the error occurred should also be output.  Suggest using: `perror( "fopen failed" );` as that function will perform all the necessary actions

Comment: regarding: `for(i=0; fgets(output, sizeof(output), filepointer) !=NULL; i++)`  the variable `i` is being completely overridden by the statement: `for(i=0;i<length;i++)`.  Therefore suggest that the `for()` statement be modified to a `while( fgets(output, sizeof(output), filepointer) )`

Comment: regarding: `return 0;` in the `main()` function.  usually the value 0 being returned to the OS indicates success, but ( in this case) a failure occurred.  Suggest using: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  (all of which is found in the header file: `stdlib.h`

Comment: regarding: `size_t length = strlen(output);

  for(size_t i=0;i<length;i++)`  no need to know the actual length of the line.  The end of the line will always have a NUL byte (0x00).  Suggest: `for( size_t i=0; output[i]; i++ )`  Which would also allow the removal of the statement: `#include <string.h>`

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. performs the desired operation
2. cleanly compiles

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
//#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 1000

struct Stack
{
    int top;
    char arr[MAX_SIZE];
};

struct Stack st;


void init()
{
    st.top = -1;
}


bool isEmpty()
{
    if(st.top == -1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


bool isFull()
{
    if(st.top == MAX_SIZE-1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


void push(char item)
{
    if( isFull() )
    {
        puts("Stack is full");
    }

    else
    {
        st.top++;
        st.arr[st.top] = item;
    }
}


void pop()
{
    if( isEmpty() )
    {
        puts( "Stack is empty" );
    }

    else
    {
        st.top--;
    }
}


char gettop()
{
    return st.arr[st.top];
}


bool ArePair(char opening,char closing)
{
    if( opening == '(' && closing == ')') 
        return true;

    else if( opening == '{' && closing == '}') 
        return true;

    else if( opening == '[' && closing == ']') 
        return true;

    return false;
}


int main( void )
{
    init();

    char output[MAX_SIZE];

    FILE * filepointer;
    filepointer = fopen("ajay1.txt", "r");


    if(filepointer == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    while( fgets(output, sizeof(output), filepointer) )
    {
        puts( "\n\necho of line read: " );
        puts( output );

        for( size_t i=0; output[i]; i++ )
        {
            if( output[i] == '\n' )
            {
                puts( "finished with current line" );
                continue;
            }

            printf( "Current char under test: %c\n", output[i] );

            if(output[i] == '(' || output[i] == '{' || output[i] == '[')
            {
                push(output[i]);
                continue;
            }

            if(output[i] == ')' || output[i] == '}' || output[i] == ']')
            {
                if( isEmpty() ) 
                {
                    puts( "unbalanced pair" );
                    continue;
                }

                if( !ArePair( gettop(), output[i]) ) 
                {
                    puts( "pair not balanced" );
                    continue;
                }

                else
                {
                    puts( "pair matched" );
                }

                pop();

            }
        }
    }

    if(isEmpty())
    {
        puts("\nResult - Valid expression - Perfectly Balanced !");
    }

    else
    {
        puts("\nResult - Invalid expression - Not a Balanced one !");
    }

    fclose(filepointer);

}
```

Given the posted file contents, here is the output:

```
echo of line read: 
()

Current char under test: (
Current char under test: )
pair matched
finished with current line


echo of line read: 
[]

Current char under test: [
Current char under test: ]
pair matched
finished with current line


echo of line read: 
[

Current char under test: [
finished with current line


echo of line read: 
]

Current char under test: ]
pair matched
finished with current line


echo of line read: 
{}

Current char under test: {
Current char under test: }
pair matched
finished with current line


echo of line read: 
{

Current char under test: {
finished with current line

Result - Invalid expression - Not a Balanced one !
```